# How do I use git-diff to see differences in a line?

Tags: git, diff

I have mysql dumps with a lot of data on a single line. I'd like to compare them with git, but even using commands such as `git diff --word-diff --word-diff-regex=.` shows you the whole line, so it's practically impossible to find the changes. how can I get git, or another tool, to output the changes with only a minimal amount of characters around ?

Comment: If you can find a tool which extracts the relevant parts out of a line, you can use `git config diff.filetype.textconf=tool`. For example, I have `git config diff.json.textconv="jq ."` in a repo where I get a lot of changes in a single line of JSON, but want to see only the changed fragments in the diff.

Comment: Hint: If you can recreate those mysql dumps, then you may want to do so using `--skip-extended-insert`. This will result in each line containing only a single record. (Alternatively you could use a tool like `sed` to manually break up the lines after the fact.)

Comment: I did end up just using notepad++ to break up line, as I always end up doing in these types of cases lol. Thanks for the cli option though, very nice !